# Illegal use of Floating Point error while compiling

Tags: c

I am getting an error as "illegal use of floating point" while running the program below.

How should I fix it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main() {
   float x,op;
   printf("enter the value of x");
   scanf("%f",&x);
   op=(x^1/2+x^2/3+x^3/4)/(x^5/2+x^7/2);
   printf("Final Op is %f\n",op);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Umm formatting fail:(

Comment: formatting fail ? what does it mean?

Comment: Also note that the 'uparrow' operator is not overloaded to mean 'raise to the power of' with floats - it's a bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: Never mind - haccks has fixed it.

Comment: Use `pow()` for exponentiation.

Comment: @PaulR; Better `powf` for `float`.

Comment: @haccks: yes, except not all compilers have powf() unfortunately (e.g. MSVC until recently).

Answer (score 3):

In C, `^` is used as the bitwise XOR operator. Each of the operands shall have integer type.

#### 6.5.11 Bitwise exclusive OR operator:

> 2 Each of the operands shall have integer type.
> 4 The result of the `^` operator is the bitwise exclusive OR of the operands [...]

You need the standard library function `powf`:

```
float powf(float x, float y);
```

Include `math.h` header in your program.

Also note that as pointed out by [@Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) `1/2`, `2/3` and `3/4` will all return `0` because they are integer division. You need to change them to `1.0/2`, `2.0/3` and `3.0/4`.

Comment: One could perhaps also mention that things like `1/2` are probably not what OP expects.

Comment: Also note that `powf` is by no means universal, especially if OP is using an old compiler like Turbo C or MSVC (which is likely given the use of `conio.h`).

Comment: @PaulR;  Turbo C++ is obsolete and MSVC is not C compiler but visual C compiler.

Comment: @haccks: unfortunately Turbo C and Turbo C++ are still widely used, e.g. in Indian colleges, and MSVC also supports C89 and `conio.h` (recent versions also partially support C99). OP most likely will get an error if he tries to use `powf`.

Comment: @PaulR : A slight misrepresentation of MSVC++'s C runtime library; [MSDN: pow,powf,powl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt5dakze.aspx).  Edit - sorry; you did mention that in another comment.

Comment: @Clifford: yes, the float versions were added relatively recently (the page you link to is for VS 2013).

Comment: @PaulR : Yes I note that you mentioned that earlier - apologies.  Using C++ compilation of course they were always overloaded (though an implementation may have simply cast the C89 library double implementation).

Comment: No problem - I just speak from bitter experience after years of writing cross-platform C code where MSVC is always the "lowest common denominator" and having to work around all the stuff that Microsoft couldn't be bothered to implement.

Answer (score 0):

In C and related languages `^` is the bitwise XOR operator. For exponentiation you need `pow()` or `powf()`.

Change:

```
op=(x^1/2+x^2/3+x^3/4)/(x^5/2+x^7/2);
```

to:

```
op = (pow(x, 1./2) + pow(x, 2./3) + pow(x, 3./4)) / (pow(x, 5./2) + pow(x, 7./2));
```

Make sure you `#include <math.h>`.

Also you might want to get a good introductory book on C and read up on operators and math library functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float x, op;
    printf("Enter the value of x: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    op = (pow(x, 1./2) + pow(x, 2./3) + pow(x, 3./4)) / (pow(x, 5./2) + pow(x, 7./2));
    printf("\nFinal op is %f\n", op);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/7mfAtR)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot but after including the above pow in my program now different error pops up as below.

Comment: function 'pow' should have a prototype

Comment: @chandramouli: Check that you have `#include <math.h>` at the top of your program. Make sure you don't have any additional punctuation or other typos on that line.

Comment: hey Paul ! , yes i have included #include <math.h> even after that am getting this error and now i re write program even after that am facing same issue.In addition to it am getting few more as below errors now:

Comment: function 'printf' should have prototype

Comment: function 'scanf' should have prototype

Comment: Click on the `LIVE DEMO` button in my answer above to see what your fixed code should look like. It sounds like you may have deleted `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: hey paull i copied the program from live demo and now compiler through error pop up  1. CPP2 bad file name format  in include  directive             2.CPP 8 :- Function 'pow' should have a prototype

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code or did you re-type it ? If you typed it then you may have made a mistake somewhere - try copy and paste so this can't happen. Check also for garbage characters in the source code. If you still can't fix it then try a different IDE, e.g Code::Blocks with gcc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the `op` expression:

1. `^` is not the exponential operator in C, it is bitwise-XOR and required integer operands.
2. When both operands of `/` are integers, then an integer divide is performed, which truncates to the integer nearest zero.  So for example `7/2 == 3`.  You must make one or both operands floating point to perform floating point division such that `7.0/2.0 == 3.5`

.

```
#include <math.h>

...
 op = ( pow( x, 1.0/2.0 ) +
        pow( x, 2.0/3.0 ) +
        pow( x, 3.0/4.0) ) / 
      ( pow( x, 5.0/2.0 ) + 
        pow( x, 7.0/2.0 ) ;
```

Note that the expression involves an implicit cast to `float`.  In C89 the math functions are defined for `double` - so the cast cannot be avoided. C99 provides `float` variants; e.g. `powf()`, and C++ overloads them so that the type is determined by the operands; e.g. `pow(7.0f/2.0f)`.